# Create new site collection usingSave site as template

Tags: 2013, 2010

I have saved site as template in solution gallery of a site. After that how can I create different site collection in same web application using this template?

My Requirement is that some new site collections to be create  with new database
and this site collection has some document libraries ,content types and site columns.
So every time when i create new site collection just i want to use site template is it can be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices would tell you not to do this because it's not always going to work, depending on Site type, language settings etc. But you can do it by following these steps:

- Save site as a template in Solutions Gallery
- Download the site template from solutions gallery to a file.
- Upload the site template file to solution gallery

[Save, download, and upload a SharePoint 2013 site as a template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj938033.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Hi please see my updated question what i need i do not want to create same site collections repeatedly instead use site template

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the template to create a new sitecollection but you can use the template to create a subsite within a different sitecollection, like described by Rafael. Just make sure that same sitecollection features are active on the site where you want to re-use the template.

Comment: but in below link it can be http://blog.ciaops.com/2013/07/using-site-template-with-new-site.html ; i want to create new site collection in same web application